# Google maps Android in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-studio-2.1

I have created a maps activity in android studio and now for some reasons i want to implement it in eclipse. So i copied the below code:

Activity:

```
package my1.app;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static double latitude;
    private static double longtitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();

        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(12);

    }



    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Log.i("mike",Double.toString(latitude));
        Log.i("mike",Double.toString(longtitude));
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                Log.i("mike",Double.toString(latitude));
                Log.i("mike",Double.toString(longtitude));
                LatLng here = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(here).title("My Current Position")
                        .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)) );
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        /*try {
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1337);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }catch(SecurityException se){
            Log.e("Mike1", se.getMessage());
            se.printStackTrace();
        }*/


    }
}
```

layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="my1.app.MainActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my1.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="thekey" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i created a lib folder in the project and copied google play services classed.jar that i extracted from google-play-services-maps.aar and i added it to the build path.

Also i changed references to Support and Compat (like SupportMapFragment to MapFragment, AppCompatActivity to Activity etc)

the error i get:

```
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441): Process: my1.app, PID: 14441
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my1.app/my1.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my1.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my1.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my1.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my1.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my1.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my1.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    ... 9 more
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my1.app.MainActivity
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        ... 13 more
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my1.app.MainActivity
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):        ... 12 more
07-22 12:07:46.631: E/AndroidRuntime(14441):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

What should i do to make it work?

Comment: have to tried clean and build again ?

Comment: Looks like the path to the activity in Eclipse is changed. And if you just copy the full code of activity from AndroidStudio, you have wrong package path in the first line of activity: `package my1.app;`

Comment: the package is correct. I did not copy everything without checking these details.